# How to do accordion between HTML TR using JQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, html-table

I have a table where I use `tr` as heading. Some `tr` have a class `accordion`. I need to toggle by default all the `accordion` class. Once I click on it, it should open all the follow `tr` **till** it find the next `accordion` class. For example. If I click on the `tr` that has the class `cities`. It should open only the next two `tr` (bangkok and sao paulo).  But no idea so far how to do it.

**HTML**

```
    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top" class="fruits accordion"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="orange"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="apple"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="cities accordion"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="bangkok"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="são paulo"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="countries accordion"></tr>
            <tr valign="top" class="brazil">
            <tr valign="top" class="england">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JQUERY (not working)**

```
    $(function() {
    $(".form-table tr:not(.accordion)").hide();
    $(".form-table").find("tr.accordion").click(function(){
       $(this).siblings("tr:not(.accordion)").fadeToggle(500);
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `nextUntil()` will get you started. It collects all siblings  up until the selector that is passed to it.

```
$(".form-table tr:not(.accordion)").hide(); /* replace this with CSS , more efficient */

$(".form-table tr.accordion").click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);
});
```

**[nextUntil() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)**

Table elements don't animate well, you may want to consider changing structure

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rueLuL/1/)</kbd>